# Como resetar o InputStream

Tags: java

Tenho um WebService que salva a foto em uma pasta do servidor que foi enviada pelo aplicativo Android através do seguinte código:

```
       ...

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File( caminhodestinofotos + uploadedFileName ));
        while (( read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        ...
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém decidimos salvar essa foto na base de dados.

Para esse fim pensei em transformar o InputStream que chega a função do WebService em um array de bytes.

Adicionei ao inicio da função a seguinte linha:

```
byte[] arrbytes =  sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(uploadedInputStream, -1, true);
```

Acontece que após a execução dessa linha o LOOP que lê do arquivo adiciona ao array bytes não acontece.

A linha `read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1` retorna -1 como se o InputStream estivesse no final do arquivo e uma leitura sequencial não pode ocorrer novamente.

Como devo proceder? Como resetar e colocar o ponteiro de leitura no inicio do
arquivo novamente, ou qual seria uma outra maneira de usar esse mesmo InputStream para salvar em arquivo e salvar na base de dados?

Grato.

Comment: Olá, no InputStream há dois métodos para isso: o `mark(int readLimit)` e o `reset()`. O `mark` faz o que o nome diz, marca um ponto no arquivo. O `reset()` reseta exatamente para esse ponto. Tenta usar um `mark(1000)` antes da linha que deseja ler em loop, e no final dar o `reset()`. Não sei exatamente se é isso que procurava, por isso não coloquei como resposta.

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo erro: java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported

Comment: Pode editar o seu post com o código completo desse método?

Comment: O inputStream que chegava a função não suportava marcar e resetar. 
Copie para um outro que suportasse assim : BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(uploadedInputStream);  e trabalhei com esse. Marquei copiei para a bytes[] array, resetei e salvei na tabela. Ofereça a resposta que para que eu posso aceita-la.

Comment: Pronto, fico feliz que tenha resolvido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, no [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) há dois métodos para isso:

`mark(int readLimit)` - Faz o que o nome diz, marca um ponto no arquivo.

`reset()` - Reseta exatamente para o ponto marcado pelo método acima.

Sugiro tentar usar um mark(1000) antes da linha que deseja ler em loop, e no final dar o reset(), assim o leitor voltará para onde marcou e executará o read().

Comment: Antes de usar esses métodos é conveniente usar o markSupported() para ver se ele suporta, senão é necessário copiar para outro que suporte.

Comment: Não sabia dessa. Nunca me deu problema sem o markSupported() na verdade. Mas é sempre bom saber, haha.